# CE 1.9 - If Category Layered Navigation has 0 Filters changed to One Page Column template

Tags: magento-1.9, category, template, layered-navigation

Currently using the 2-column-left template for category pages. The layered navigation shows up on the left (with attribute filters) but when there is nothing to show (no attributes for that specific category) the entire left column ends up being a vast empty space.

For these specific categories that have no filter attributes to show i would like to avoid this whitespace by switching to the one column template but only for those categories that have no attributes.

How can i achieve this please? If not through templates perhaps there is a way to add a CSS selector where i can modify the width to 100% based on the presence of the selector?

Comment: have you got solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I figured out how to add a body class for the category page but i've been unable to figure out how to remove/add this class when there are no filters.